# How to change the directory where blazegraph store data?

Tags: rdf, blazegraph

I am trying to change the directory where blazegraph store its data.

Right now, the data is stored in `/var/lib/blazegraph/blazegraph.jnl` I tried to change BLZG_DATA in `/etc/default/blazegraph` and `/usr/bin/blazegraph` but data is still stored in `/var/lib/blazegraph/`.

I am running ubuntu cosmic and the following blazegraph:

```
buildVersion=2.1.4
gitCommit=738d05f08cffd319233a4bfbb0ec2a858e260f9c
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Blazegraph 2.1.5 running in Tomcat on a Linux Debian

change these files

```
./tomcat/webapps/blazegraph/WEB-INF/GraphStore.properties
line:12:com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.file=bigdata.jnl
./tomcat/webapps/blazegraph/WEB-INF/classes/RWStore.properties
line:12:com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.file=bigdata.jnl
```

to

```
./tomcat/webapps/blazegraph/WEB-INF/GraphStore.properties
line:12:com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.file=/your/desired/path/bigdata.jnl
./tomcat/webapps/blazegraph/WEB-INF/classes/RWStore.properties
line:12:com.bigdata.journal.AbstractJournal.file=/your/desired/path/bigdata.jnl
```